# TransitionDrawable flickers

Tags: android

I have a picture of a lightbulb

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/light_bulb_off" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/light_bulb_on" />
</transition>
```

I also have the folowing method to turn on/off this lightbulb depending on condition

```
private void ImageClick(boolean b) {
    final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    TransitionDrawable drawable = (TransitionDrawable) image
            .getDrawable();
        if (b) {
            drawable.startTransition(1000); //Turn on
        } else {
            drawable.reverseTransition(1000); //Turn off
        }
}
```

Now, if I call this method from a button, in normal intervals like 2seconds, everything is fine, the light turns on and there is a nice transition effect

but I also have a background thread that pols a server with 500ms intervals to get some data

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable;
int delay = 500; 
String DeviceIP = "192.168.101.11";

private void StartNetworkThread() {
    handler.postDelayed( runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            UpdateDeviceStatus();

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
}
private void UpdateDeviceStatus() {

    //See every device if its online or not
    String url = "";
    url = MainActivity.internetOptions.getURL() + "/" + DeviceIP + "/cm?cmnd=Power";
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.d("HTTP", "Device: " + DeviceIP + " failed");
            DeviceActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ImageClick(false);
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String myResponse = response.body().string();
                if (myResponse.equals("{\"POWER\":\"ON\"}")) {
                    Log.d("HTTP", "Device: " + DeviceIP + " works");
                    DeviceActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ImageClick(true);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    DeviceActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ImageClick(false);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now the problem is, if this background thread is calling this ImageClick method, which should turn light on on transition, light blinks like a broken flurescent tube

Instead of light being on all the time (since ImageClick(true) most of the time, because server tells that light is on)

so TLRD:
if you call ImageClick(true) 2 times in a row, instead of light staying on, it blinks

Now I don't know why it blinks (flickers, there is no transition, just anoying flicker which makes you go crazy if you look at it long enough), but if it has to blink (it also blinks if I drawable.startTransition(0); (0 should mean no transition so keep light on), so if the light has to blink it should blink with 50Hz, but I would much prefer it staying on if you call ImageClick(true) 2 times in a row

Now the light being image of a lightbulb and on state meaing show @drawable/light_bulb_on

off state meaning show @drawable/light_bulb_off

Hope someone know how to stop the image to flicker. Thanks for anwsering and Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, with a few more if statments

```
int LightTurnedOnCount = 0;
int LightTurnedOffCount = 0;
void TurnWeb(boolean b) {
    final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    TransitionDrawable drawable = (TransitionDrawable) image
            .getDrawable();
    if (b && LightTurnedOnCount < 1) {
        drawable.startTransition(1000); //Turn on
        LightTurnedOnCount++;
    } else if (!b && LightTurnedOffCount < 1) {
        drawable.resetTransition(); //Turn off
        LightTurnedOffCount++;
    }
}

private void UpdateDeviceStatus() {

    //See every device if its online or not
    String url = "";
    url = MainActivity.internetOptions.getURL() + "/" + DeviceIP + "/cm?cmnd=Power";
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.d("HTTP", "Device: " + DeviceIP + " failed");
            DeviceActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TurnWeb(false);
                    LightTurnedOnCount = 0;
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String myResponse = response.body().string();
                if (myResponse.equals("{\"POWER\":\"ON\"}")) {
                    Log.d("HTTP", "Device: " + DeviceIP + " works");
                    DeviceActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            TurnWeb(true);
                            LightTurnedOffCount = 0;
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    DeviceActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            TurnWeb(false);
                            LightTurnedOnCount = 0;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The light does not flicker anymore